# ruby on rails kind of thing for java

Tags: java, frameworks

I am thinking of developing a django / ruby on rails frame work for java , (may be java on rails :)) .Can any one  give me some pointers to start with,I know we have grails or play framework in java. But any tips will be help will be helpful

Comment: You've already found them - Grails and Play.

Comment: There is also JRubyOnRails see  
http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/JRubyOnRails

Comment: You can try spring roo. See http://www.springsource.org/roo

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have somewhat answered your own question. The steps I would go through are

- fully understand django / ruby on rails
- look into Grails and Play Framework, specifically looking at the source code and the architecture of the framework
- come up with an architectural plan of how your new framework would work.

I would suggest not doing this on your own though. You would be much better off trying to gain support from other developers who see a similar need as you have, and try to do this collaboratively. They will question design choices and help to ensure a better all round product.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at http://javalite.io. This is a full stack database and web framework for rapid development, much like rails, but for Java devs.